# How to add error message to response body?

Tags: java, servlets, error-handling, response, servlet-filters

I have a Java Servlet class where I try to set the error status when there is an authentication issue in my application. However, the issue is, I am able to set the error status but am not able to set an error message in the body of the response. Below is my attempt:

AuthorizationFilter.java

```
public class AuthorizationFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    private ExceptionHandler exceptionHandler;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(final ServletRequest servletRequest, final ServletResponse servletResponse, final FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
        final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

        UserSession userSession = null;
        try {
             userSession = authProvider.authenticate(request, response);
        } catch(RestUsageException throwable) {
            exceptionHandler.handle(throwable.getExceptionCode(), throwable.getMessage(), throwable, response);
            response.sendError(throwable.getRespondStatus().value());
        //  response.sendError(throwable.getRespondStatus().value(), "Message");
            return;
        }
    ...more code here
    }
```

ExceptionHandler.java

```
@Override
public void handle(String exceptionCode, String message, Throwable throwable, final ServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String json = "{  \n" +
                "   \"errorCode\":\""+exceptionCode+"\",\n" +
                "   \"errorMessage\":\""+throwable.getMessage()+"\",\n" +
                "   \"success\":\"false\",\n" +
                "   \"errorId\":\""+uuid+"\"\n" +
                "}";
    response.getOutputStream().println(json);
  //  response.getOutputStream().flush();
}
```

My `throwable` contains the correct HTTP status that I want to display. I tried two things:

1. I tried to do follow this method: public void sendError(int sc,
                     java.lang.String msg)
              throws java.io.IOException

But the message seems to only be displayed in the HTTP Status header.

2. I tried to `response.getOutputStream().flush();` to flush out the response but then when I try to perform `response.sendError(throwable.getRespondStatus().value());` afterwards, I get an error saying my `Response is already committed`, and my body shows up but the status ends up being 200.

Any ideas on how to set the error message body? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cant use the respons streams in combination with `response.sendError(...)`.
Try to use `respons.setStatus(...)` instead.

Comment: using `respons.setStatus(...)` only allows me to set any status with status 200 or more.. unless I am mistaken. If I try to set a status of anything different than 200 I get an error

Comment: Yes, you have to use a valid status code. I assumed that `throwable.getRespondStatus().value()` was a valid code.

Comment: yes, it is a valid code but hte problem is, when I call `         response.setStatus(throwable.getRespondStatus().value());`, it actually goes into my GZIP Filter where it performs:

`  public void setStatus(int sc) {
   super.setStatus(sc);
   if (sc < 200 || sc >= 300)
    noGzip();
  }
` And from there it eventually turns into `IllegalStateException`. Is there any way I can avoid going into my `GZIPFilter's setStatus()` function?

Comment: I do not know enough about your code, the solution above is what we use in our code-base. Maybe it is not applicable in your case, and I think it might be a good idea to update the question to include the filter-problem.